# how do I get the dates of even and the odd weeks by using c#

Tags: c#, datetime

how do I get the dates even and the odd weeks by using c#

must account for the

- start of month given by user
- and also accordingly the end of month with resect to the number of days possible in the month

Comment: What exactly is an "even month" or an "odd month"? Account for end of month in what way exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Calendar.GetWeekOfYear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.getweekofyear.aspx) to get the week number of the week containing any date. You can get the week number of the first day in the month, and the last day. Then you just need to find all the even/odd numbers between those two week numbers. The test `x % 2 == 0` will tell you if x is even.